# How to get a Windows virtual folder location from Java?

Tags: java, windows, jna, special-folders

I'd like to retrieve the location of a Windows virtual folder from Java. [JNA provides some support](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/KnownFolders.java) but the documentation don't explain how to directly use it.

Comment: What windows function call would you use to look it up?  Translate that into a JNA mapping and extend the appropriate JNA mapping to instantiate your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look into the [JNA source](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) reveals the javadoc of [Shell32Util.getKnownFolderPath(Guid.GUID)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Shell32Util.java#L73)

> Retrieves the full path of a known folder identified by the folder's KNOWNFOLDERID.

The local application data directory can be retrieved as

```
String localAppDataDir = Shell32Util.getKnownFolderPath(
    KnownFolders.FOLDERID_LocalAppData);
System.out.println(localAppDataDir);
```

output will be something like

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local
```

where `JohnDoe` is the name of the current user.